# How can I store html input fields in c# with slashes and double quotes?

Tags: c#

How can I escape special slash characters ?

```csharp
string first = @"document.querySelector("input[name = 'loginForm\\:j_id_f']").value ='account_name'"
```

```
string second = "document.querySelector("#loginForm\\:j_id_f").value = "hi" "
```

To compile the solution I need to solve :

- > CS0103 : The name input does not exist in the current context .
- > CS1040 : Preprocessor directives must appear as the first
  > non-whitespace charater.

Comment: You need to escape double quotes in string literals.

Comment: Also, why are you making a string variable have _code_ as a value?

Comment: Your problem are the double quotes, not the simbols inside them ;)

Comment: I think this question could be re-opened but perhaps the title should be changed as "storing input fields" is really not part of the problem - the core issue is how to handle slashes and quotes in your string. So change it to something along the lines of "Verbatim Strings in C#: How to escape slashes and handle quotes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as gunr2171 stated you have to escape double quotes.

The error complains about the name input and the # character because they don't see them as part of the string because of the double quote character in front of  them.

Try this:

```
    string first = "document.querySelector(\"input[name = 'loginForm\\:j_id_f']\").value ='account_name'";
    string second = "document.querySelector(\"#loginForm\\:j_id_f\").value = \"hi\" ";
```

Comment: And to repeat my concern, it's a _very very bad idea_ to store C# or JavaScript code inside a string. Dynamically executing code is something to be avoided until you really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Its not c# code but yeah there should be better solutions to generate html/javascript.